# Unable to run console consumer using a Kafka broker inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm having a problem running a Kafka broker in a Docker container.

I have downloaded and unpacked a tar archive of Kafka 2.12-2.4.1.

I can run Zookeeper and Kafka brokers from the command line, producing and consuming messages successfully. When I build a docker container with Zookeeper, I can run that with a Kafka broker running from the command line, again producing and consuming messages successfully. When I put the broker into a docker container, the consumers and producers can't find a broker to connect to.

I have checked to ensure that Zookeeper has a connected broker: the zookeeper "dump" command below

```
echo dump | nc localhost 2181
```

returns

```
SessionTracker dump:
Session Sets (3)/(1):
0 expire at Thu May 28 09:53:33 GMT 2020:
0 expire at Thu May 28 09:53:36 GMT 2020:
1 expire at Thu May 28 09:53:39 GMT 2020:
    0x10002dfed700008
ephemeral nodes dump:
Sessions with Ephemerals (1):
0x10002dfed700008:
    /controller
    /brokers/ids/0
Connections dump:
Connections Sets (2)/(2):
0 expire at Thu May 28 09:53:37 GMT 2020:
2 expire at Thu May 28 09:53:47 GMT 2020:
    ip: /172.18.0.1:55656 sessionId: 0x0
    ip: /172.18.0.5:48474 sessionId: 0x10002dfed700008
```

which, to my untrained eye, looks like Zookeeper has a registered broker.

I can successfully list topics with the command

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

and when I run the command

```
netstat -plnt
```

I can see that I have listeners on ports 2181 and 9092, as below

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9092                 :::*                    LISTEN      54661/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      47872/docker-proxy
```

However, when I try to connect a consumer with the command

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic aaaa
```

I get errors

```
WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-8228-1, groupId=console-consumer-8228] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

which would seem to indicate that the client can't contact the broker.

I've tried several different variations on the listeners and advertised.listeners in the broker config file, setting them to localhost and 127.0.0.1, but to no avail.

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple: can anyone help?

Comment: It is not very clear, do you have 2 containers and you try to connect from one to another using localhost as address?

Comment: Are you building your own Docker containers for your own learning? Because there are very good ones that exist already if all you want to do is run Kafka + Zookeeper on Docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka

Comment: Also where you are running you Consumer from? Your host machine, or another Docker container?

Comment: I have two containers and I'm trying to connect from one to another, I am doing this as a learning exercise, and I'm running the consumer from my host machine - although I tried to run it from another Docker container, with the same results.

Comment: To explain a little further, I have two containers, one running Zookeeper and the other running a broker.

Comment: I have updated the broker config file as per the answer from Giorgios below (with the confluent properties, translated to the config equivalents, added to the config file). I have created docker containers for the consumer and producer. The dockerised containers work successfully: when run from the command line, they fail with the same "bootstrap broker disconnected" error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to configure the following:

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-host:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka-host:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-host:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL
```

---

- Now all your clients that run within the Docker Network, should use

  ```
  LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-host:29092
  ```
- All clients outside the Docker Network should use

  ```
  LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka-host:9092
  ```

---

For a more comprehensive guide, read [@RobinMoffatt article](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Comment: Thanks, Giorgos, but from the article it looks like those values are for a prebuilt container (I think Confluent?): I'm building my own, so I need to set the corresponding values in the config file.

Comment: So, I tried this with exactly the same result. I can run consumers and producers inside docker, and these work, but I can't connect from a bash session outside docker.

Comment: @GraemeBurton What values did you use for `kafka-host` ?

Comment: I have the internal host set to `server` and the external host set to `localhost`. I think you're on the right track, though - I found [this article](https://medium.com/@marcelo.hossomi/running-kafka-in-docker-machine-64d1501d6f0b) which could well help - I'll implement it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have solved the problem and I now have a working Docker/Kafka environment: I have a zookeeper, a broker and a consumer running in docker, and I can produce messages both from a producer running in docker and a consumer running from a command line.

As @GiorgosMyrianthous suspected, the problem was with the listeners and advertised listeners. I entered the following values in the Kafka broker properties file

`listeners=PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://server:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT`

and I started the container with port 9092 exposed to the outside world.

I ran the Docker consumer with the bootstrap server set to `server:29092`.

I ran the Docker producer with the bootstrap server set to `server:29092`.

I ran the command line producer with the bootstrap server set to `localhost:9092`.

Messages typed in either of the producers appeared in the consumer.